# Silverlight. Play video from byte array

Tags: silverlight, video, byte, mediaelement

I have Silverlight application that recieves special structure of media: images and videos.
Data is recieved as byte[] for each image or video

To show images, I use:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Node.ResourceBin);

BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
bmp.SetSource(stream);

ImageContainer.Source = bmp;
```

And it works.

To show video I have tried:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

stream.Write(Node.ResourceBin, 0, Node.ResourceBin.Length);
stream.Position = 0;          

VideoContainer.SetSource(stream);                
VideoContainer.Play();
```

And it doesnt work. I compared length of byte[] and original AVI file and they are equals, so, data recieved correctly.

What's wrong with it?

Thanks

Comment: Before you play it is there anything in the stream? Also Close the stream

Comment: Have you verified that Silverlight can play the video without loading it with a stream? Most video issues I've had relate to codec support.

Comment: Are you downloading these videos?

Comment: Well if its empty then Node.ResourceBin is empty

Comment: Why are you writing to instead of reading from Node.ResourceBin?

Comment: Please, read post carefully. I wrote that length of Node.ResourceBin equals to length of initial video file on hard drive. It is NOT empty. Stream.Write() - writes to stream, not to byte[]

Comment: I have tried to add video to resources and set Source of MediaElement to "/GraphManager.WebViewer;component/myvideo.avi". SL doesnt show it.....

Comment: Now try the same method using a WMV file. If it works then you've found your problem.

Comment: @Renatus good call.  Not sure what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1):

> Have you verified that Silverlight can play the video without loading
>   it with a stream? Most video issues I've had relate to codec support.
>   – The Real Baumann 9 hours ago

SL plays only WMV format. AVI doesnt play at all. Thanks.

Look here: http://forums.silverlight.net/t/9498.aspx/1

> Yes. According to the overview of Silverlight,it currently support
>   (VC-1, WMV, WMA, MP3) and 720P High Definition (HD) Video.

Answer (score 0):

From all the comments I believe I know whats going on.

When your loading a video from a resource DO NOT use a stream. Just set the source using Source()

```
VideoContainer.Source("/GraphManager.WebViewer;component/myvideo.avi");                
VideoContainer.Play();
```

When your downloading video files from the internet then use a stream

Comment: I believe he's probably using a stream with intent to load files from the internet, but testing it against a local file. And from the comments, he said he tried using it as the direct source of a MediaElement, so it's more than likely a codec issue.

Comment: How can it be a codec issue. Windows Vista/7. Plays .avi files out of the box just fine

Comment: Silverlight != Windows Vista/7.

Comment: Didn't say it did. But why would a programmer be developing Silverlight somewhere else?

Comment: The point is, just because Vista/7 can play AVI files by default doesn't mean that the Silverlight plugin can't.