# How to show video from byte array?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, video-processing

I am working with `Silverlight`. I have created `MemoryStreamVideoSink` which is inherited from `VideoSink`.

In method `OnSample(long sampleTime, long frameDuration, byte[] sampleData)`

So my task is to show video from byte byte[] sampleData. Is it possible?

Comment: Radislav - was it helpful for you? )

Comment: possible duplicate of [Silverlight. Play video from byte array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100177/silverlight-play-video-from-byte-array)

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the format of your video supported from `Silverlight` or not.

And taks a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9100177/silverlight-play-video-from-byte-array) please.